# Three.js Canvas renderer, Objectloader with a Blender JSON file, transparency on object overlap?

Tags: canvas, three.js, textures

I'm using Three.JS to render a Blender Object exported as a scene, so it is using the ObjectLoader, not the Json Loader.  I am also using the CanvasRendering engine.  The issue occurs when there is an overlap on the object; it is doing a semi-transparent effect on the material.

[image: weird overlap render]

It doesn't matter what sort of blender export I'm using; I've picked and exported other Blender files and they all do this effect, no matter the settings.

[image]

The following is the code I'm using to place the object and the material.

```
var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
            loader.load("../js/lights.json", function(object) {

                   var material = new THREE.MeshToonMaterial( { color: 0x3f3f3f, alphaTest: 0.5 } );
                   object.traverse( function ( child ) {
                    if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                        child.material = material;
                        child.drawMode = THREE.TrianglesDrawMode;
                    };  
                   });
                   object.scale.set(3, 3, 3);
                   object.position.x = 1;
                   object.position.y = 1;
                   object.position.z = 1;
                   object.rotation.set( 25, 25, 25 );
                   scene.add( object );
                }   
            );
```

I've played with the material type, from Lambert to Phong, and I'm still getting this overlap transparency issue.  What is it I'm missing?  Thanks!

EDIT: After the comments, I've made the changes requested.  The WebGL Renderer is now being used instead of Canvas.  This is now what I have, the model isn't showing up at all now, but I have no errors in my console.

```
var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
            loader.load("../js/lights.json", function(object) {

                   var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x333333 } );
                   object.traverse( function ( child ) {
                    if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                        child.material = material;
                        child.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
                        child.material.overdraw = 0.5
                    };  
                   });
                   object.scale.set(3, 3, 3);
                   object.position.x = 1;
                   object.position.y = 1;
                   object.position.z = 1;
                   object.rotation.set( 25, 25, 25 );
                   scene.add( object );
                }   
            );
```

Comment: it looks like your triangle normals are not all pointing in the same direction. try using the `computeVertexNormals()` call and use the webgl renderer for better results. Also use a lambert or phong material which you say you have tried and use the default `drawMode`.

Comment: I just made the changes you recommended, and the screen turned black.

Comment: do you have lights defined in the scene?

Comment: Yes.  '            function initLights() {
                var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
            light.position.set(50, 50, 50);
                scene.add(light);
            }'

Comment: I got the lights back on by adding: `renderer.setClearColor (0xffffff, 1);`, but the object isn't loading at all and there are no js errors.

Comment: well now you are clearing the browser window to white and your ambient light is very strong so everything becomes white. Try ambient color `0x404040` and renderer clear color green `0x00ff00` to really see if something is getting drawn.

Comment: Solid Green.  I see nothing but solid green, sorry.

Comment: and there are no errors in the console?

Comment: none, sorry.  Console is error clear

Comment: It's not an error, but I am getting a console message now that says" THREE.WebGLRenderer 87" . Could this help?

Comment: no, thats just the version of three.js you are running

Comment: alright.  is there anything else I can try?  It's weird that my object will vanish just because I change the renderer, right?

Comment: is there any way that you can post the model?

Comment: Absolutely, thank you.   https://www.dropbox.com/s/r78rcfwbbjcp4l3/lights.json?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model is outside your viewport, thats why you dont see it. Load your model in https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qPmyPz?editors=0010 and you can see it fine. Now comment the lines 80-82 (which is the default behavior) and reload your model. You are not able to see it anymore.

These lines turn the `controls` so you can see the model:

```
var bb = new THREE.Box3()
bb.setFromObject(scene);
bb.center(controls.target);
```

Comment: Thanks!  One problem, I forgot to mention it, I'm doing a movement that's a subtle shift depending on the mouse movement.  That appears to be at odds with the controls commands from the codepin. I'll show you the relevant code:

https://pastebin.com/KfmmVDP5

Comment: that was just an example. it does not mean that you have to use it verbatim. Another way to get the above functionality is to use the camera `lookAt()` and point it to the `bb.center`

Comment: Thanks! marking as solved!  You've been very patient and good.